# Signtool Unexpected token 'sign'

Tags: signtool

I went through the questions but could not find the exact same issue as what I am encountering.

I installed Signtool following the instructions under Windows 11, and am trying to apply the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-sign-a-file

I simply type :

```
signtool sign myprog.exe
```

And I get the below. What gives ? :

At line:1 char:72
... les (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x64\Signtool" sign ChecksB ...
~~~~
Unexpected token 'sign' in expression or statement.
CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken**

Answer (score 0):

The output looks strange, you seem to be in a folder called "Signtool". If you use Powershell you need to use `.\` to invoke an application in the current directory, for example:

```
cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86\'
```

and then

```
.\signtool.exe sign C:\myprog.exe
```